# Avoiding improper std::string initialization with NULL const char* using g++

Tags: c++, g++, stdstring

A there any g++ options which can detect improper initialization of std::string with NULL const char*?

I was in the process of turning some int fields into std::string ones, i.e:

```
struct Foo
{
   int id;
   Foo() : id(0) {} 
};
```

...turned into:

```
struct Foo
{
   std::string id;
   Foo() : id(0) {} //oooops!
};
```

I completely overlooked bad 'id' initialization with 0 and g++ gave me no warnings at all. This error was detected in the run time(std::string constructor threw an exception) but I'd really like to detect such stuff in the compile time. Is there any way?

Comment: Unfortunately, 0 is the one value which won't trigger an error for an invalid conversion from int to pointer. Because of course 0 is a null pointer constant, so is convertible to any pointer type. I don't know of anything you can do other than, as visitor says, not write that initializer in the first place.

Comment: The proper solution would have been to add a private constructor `std::string::string(int);`. That would be a better match, and thus cause a compile-time error.

Comment: Not sure whether you meant it this way, but that might actually work, as a one-time test to catch any errors resulting from this round of changes from `int` to `string`. Modify `std::basic_string` in g++'s standard headers, check that the new code compiles, then change it back fast, before anyone notices.

Comment: Oh, no changing standard headers is not an option :) But probably I should ask g++ devs to add the private int constructor in the future?

Comment: Since C++23, there's a deleted `std::string::string(std::nullptr_t)` constructor that will cause this to be ill-formed, with diagnostic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is actually undefined behavior and not checked by the compiler. You are lucky that this implementation throws an exception.

However, you can avoid such problems by specifying that you want default or zero-initialization in a type-agnostic way:

```
struct Foo
{
   X id;
   Foo() : id() {} //note empty parenthesis
};
```

Comment: Hm...so you are saying default constructor for int type assigns 0 ?

Comment: This syntax means zero-initialization for built-in types.

Answer (score 8):

I can't think of a way to detect this at compile-time, so I wrote a string builder function that properly deals with null pointers:

```
//  FUNCTION :      safe_string(char const* pszS)
//  PARAMATERS :    pszS        source string to build a string from (may be NULL or 0-length)
//  DESCRIPTION :   Safely builds a string object from a char*, even a NULL pointer
//  RETURNS :       string

template<class C>
inline basic_string<C> safe_string(const C* input)
{
    if( !input )
        return basic_string<C>();
    return basic_string<C>(input);
}
```

I use this whenever I create a string and there's a chance the input might be NULL.

Answer (score 3):

There is infrastructure in GCC to produce exactly this sort of warning:

```
void foo(const char* cstr) __attribute__((nonnull (1)));

void bar() {
    foo(0);
}
```

when compiled with `-Wnonnull` (which is implied by `-Wall`) produces:

```
warning: null argument where non-null required (argument 1)
```

So in principle you ought to be able to modify the relevant system header (or, better for experimenting, modify your own $HOME/bits/basic_string.h copy and then override the system one with `-isystem $HOME`) similarly:

```
basic_string(const _CharT* __s, const _Alloc& __a = _Alloc())
    __attribute__((nonnull (1)));
```

However this doesn't help because (at least in 4.0.1) `-Wnonnull` is not supported in C++ and the attribute is apparently ignored.  It's not obvious why this is so; perhaps it was felt that it interacted badly with overloading or something.

Comment: Actually your `basic_string` ctor `__attribute__((nonnull (1)))` above checks that the `this` pointer is not `NULL`; simply change to `__attribute__((nonnull (2)))` to check that `__s` is non-null; see http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2006-04/msg00549.html