# Assign a nullptr to a std::string is safe?

Tags: c++, string, std

I was working on a little project and came to a situation where the following happened:

```
std::string myString;
#GetValue() returns a char*
myString = myObject.GetValue();
```

My question is if `GetValue()`  returns NULL `myString` becomes an empty string? Is it undefined? or it will segfault?

Comment: This question is pretty similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407711/avoiding-improper-stdstring-initialization-with-null-const-char-using-g

Comment: Microsoft always had a bug where assigning a 0x0 to std::string was OK. By looking at your code it seems like you are a microsoft guy, so it might work for you. But.. otherwise it would trigger a SIGSEGV.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Interesting little question.  According to the C++11 standard, sect. 21.4.2.9,

```
basic_string(const charT* s, const Allocator& a = Allocator());
```

*Requires: s shall not be a null pointer.*

Since the standard does not ask the library to throw an exception when this particular requirement is not met, it would appear that passing a null pointer provoked undefined behavior.

Answer (score 14):

It is runtime error.

You should do this:

```
myString = ValueOrEmpty(myObject.GetValue());
```

where `ValueOrEmpty` is defined as:

```
std::string ValueOrEmpty(const char* s)
{
    return s == nullptr ? std::string() : s;
}
```

Or you could return `const char*` (it makes better sense):

```
const char* ValueOrEmpty(const char* s)
{
    return s == nullptr ? "" : s; 
}
```

If you return `const char*`, then at the call-site, it will convert into `std::string`.

Answer (score 8):

> My question is if GetValue() returns NULL myString becomes an empty string? Is it undefined? or it will segfault?

It's undefined behavior. The compiler and run time can do whatever it wants and still be compliant.

Answer (score 8):

### Update:

Since C++23 adopted [P2166](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p2166r1.html), it is now forbidden to construct `std::string` from `nullptr`, that is, `std::string s = nullptr` or `std::string s = 0` will [no longer be well-formed](https://godbolt.org/z/vb78P5Gz7).

Comment: This answer seems to refer to initialization at compile time, but it does not tell what will happen when the `nullptr` is returned from a function where the compiler cannot deduce the value at compile time (as scetched in the question),

Comment: So now our constructors have to look like this trash "MyClass( const char *internal_name ) : name{ internal_name ? internal_name : "" } {} Yet another reason to avoid the everything everywhere all at once "standard" library.