# C++ How to detect when nullptr is passed to function where std::string is expected?

Tags: c++, string, nullptr

i could not find threads giving a clear answer on this -

i have a constructor, for example:

```
FanBookPost::FanBookPost(Fan* owner, std::string content);
```

Fan is another class in my code, but content is the problematic one:

since std::string is not a pointer, i would expect that calling the constructor with (fan, nullptr) would not be possible. however, it compiles! ... and crashes at runtime with EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

is this avoidable?

Comment: Pass the string by reference. `FanBookPost::FanBookPost(Fan* owner, std::string &content);`

Comment: "" is allowed as legit content @Smac89

Comment: If you *really* want to, you can overload it with a `const char *` version that forwards if not null.

Comment: Crash will occure when the `std::string` constructor is called, its not a problem of your code.

Comment: You can overload it with a function that takes a `std::nullptr_t`. Non-null-pointer-constants won't choose this overload.

Comment: @chris im gonna do the overload just to be safe. can you post it as comment so i can accept answer? thanks everyone else too for replying

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10771864/assign-a-nullptr-to-a-stdstring-is-safe

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour The null pointer is a perfectly valid pointer, `char` or otherwise. The only problem is that `std::string`'s constructor does not accept it.

Comment: @dyp Though this will *not* prevent things like `char *c = 0; FanBookPost fbp(..., c);` or even `FanBookPost fbp(..., 0);`.

Comment: @dyp, Good one. I like that better.

Comment: @delnan True, but that's "more obviously flawed" IMHO (i.e. it's more obvious the `char*` will be interpreted as a string and is required to point to a null-terminated array).

Comment: @delnan `0` is a null pointer constant.

Comment: @dyp `0` is not of type `nullptr_t` though.

Comment: @MarkB But the conversion to `nullptr_t` is a Standard Conversion, whereas the conversion to `string` is a User-Defined Conversion. The Standard Conversion is "better", so the `nullptr_t` overload is preferred.

Comment: @dyp An already existing `char *` being null is much *less* obviously flawed than passing `nullptr` verbatim. RE overload priority: Interesting, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @delnan It's an error that's harder to detect, I agree, but when you pass a `char*`, I think it's (at least more) reasonable to assume it must be valid.

Comment: @dyp I don't quite get your angle. Yes, some random `char *` has a higher (namely > 0%) chance of not being null, but when it *is* null, it's much harder to pin down how and why. Also, given that many people (myself included) are very inclined to code for the happy case ignore the possibility of pointers being null if it's not shoved in their face, seeing `f(c_str)` they won't check whether (1) `f` accepts null or (2) `c_str` can't be null. In contrast, `f(nullptr)` makes it hard to ignore the possibility of a null pointer.

Comment: @delnan My remark wasn't about error detection, but about assuming what happens. When I see `f(nullptr)` compile, I'm more inclined to assume that `f` can handle null pointers than when I see this fails but (only) `f(c)` compiles. Of course, a check for null pointers is reasonable and useful in an interface (essentially where you don't want to rely on the user of the interface keeping a non-nullptr guarantee).

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that the crash will occure when the constructor of `std::string` is called (as a nullptr interpreted as `const char*` is accessed there). There is nothing here you can do against this but to tell other peoples not to do shit. Its not a problem of your constructor and thus not your responsibility (besides that you cant prevent it).

Answer (score 3):

What you're observing is that you can implicitly create a `std::string` from a character pointer (`nullptr` in this case) which is then passed to the function. However creating a `string` from a null pointer is not allowed. There is nothing wrong with your method signature, just the client use that violates the `std::string` constructor's contract.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a proxy / wrapper typ, if you really want to be safe:

```
template<typename T>
struct e_t
{
public:
    inline e_t ( e_t const & other )
        : m_value( other.m_value )
    {}

    inline T & value( void )                { return m_value; }
    inline operator T&()                    { return m_value;   }
    inline e_t( const T& c ) : m_value( c )     {}

private:
    T m_value;
};

void FanBookPost(int* owner, e_t<std::string> content) {
}

int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    //FanBookPost(&n, 0); // compiler error
    //FanBookPost(&n, nullptr); // compiler error
    //FanBookPost(&n, ""); // unfortunately compiler error too
    FanBookPost(&n, std::string(""));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `std::string` has a non-explicit ctor that takes a `char *` as its sole (required) parameter. This gives an implicit conversion from `nullptr` to `std::string`, but gives undefined behavior, because that ctor specifically requires a non-null pointer.

There are a few ways to prevent this. Probably the most effective would be to take a (non-const) reference to a `std::string`, which will require passing a (non-temporary) `string` as the parameter.

```
FanBookPost::FanBookPost(Fan* owner, std::string &content);
```

This does have to unfortunate side effect of giving the function the ability to modify the string that's passed. It also means that (with a conforming compiler<sup>1</sup>) you won't be able to pass `nullptr` *or* a string literal to the function--you'll have to pass an actual instance of `std::string`.

If you want to be able to pass a string literal, you can then add an overload that takes a `char const *` parameter, and possibly one that takes a `nullptr_t` parameter as well. The former would check for a non-null pointer before creating a string and calling the function that takes a reference to a string, and the latter would do something like log the error and unconditionally kill the program (or, just possibly, log the error and throw an exception).

That's annoying and inconvenient, but *may* be superior to the current situation.

---

1. Unfortunately, the last time I noticed MS VC++ did not conform in this respect. It allows passing a temporary object by non-const reference. Normally that's fairly harmless (it just lets you modify the temporary, but that normally has no visible side effects). In this case it's much more troublesome though, since you're depending on it specifically to prevent passing a temporary object.

Comment: I'd recommend using [`/Za`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k0w269d.aspx) (disable language extensions).